# Single.zip completing before onSuccess

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I want to combine the response of 2 singles in one object

```
override fun buildUseCase(params: Int): Single<EventDetails> {
    return eventDetailsComponent.getEventDetails(params)
        .zipWith(bookingComponent.getBookingPage(bookingParams), BiFunction { details, page ->
              return@BiFunction details.apply { booking_page = page } })
}
```

But when I subscribe I'm not receiving onSuccess cause one of the singles completes before the other

```
fun loadEventDetails(id: Int) {
 usecase.execute(id)
.doOnSubscribe(onSubscribe)
.observeOn(SchedulerProvider.mainThread)
.subscribeBy(onSuccess = { details -> setValues(details) },onError = onError)
.addTo(subscriptions)
}
```

What should I do to combine those calls? or to receive onSuccess in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I forgot to `observeOn` the main thread